# Generalizing Titu's Lemma

Tags: inequality, contest-math, holder-inequality

I found a nice generalization of Titu's Lemma and was wondering if this has a name or has a reference anywhere.

Let $m$ be an integer greater than or equal to 2, $a_i^m$ a non-negative real number, and $x_i$ a positive real number. Then,

$$n^{m-2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i^m}{x_i} \geq \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)^m}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$

This reduces to Titu's Lemma when $m = 2$

Proof:
By Hölder's inequality,

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\right)^{\frac{m-2}{m}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i^m}{x_i}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{\frac{1}{m}} \geq
\sum_{i=1}^{n}1^{\frac{m-2}{m}}\left(\frac{a_i^m}{x_i}\right)^\frac{1}{m}x_i^\frac{1}{m}$$

$$n^{\frac{m-2}{m}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i^m}{x_i}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{\frac{1}{m}} \geq
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$$

$$n^{m-2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i^m}{x_i} \geq \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)^m}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$

Comment: If you use Holder's inequality, $m$ is not necessarily an integer.

Answer (score 4):

I found an even more general form in the paper [Generalizations and Refinements for Bergström and Radon's Inequalities](https://www.icstm.ro/DOCS/josa/josa_2008_1/a.10_GENERALIZATIONS_AND_REFINEMENTS_FOR_BERGSTROM_AND_RADONS_INEQUALITIES.pdf) The paper refers to it as a generalization of Radon's inequality:

> If $a_k, x_k > 0$, $p>0$, and $r \geq p+1$, then
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k^r}{a_k^p} \geq \frac{1}{n^{r-p-1}} \cdot \frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^r}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^p}$$

When $p = 1$ and $r = 2$, it becomes Titu's Lemma (also known as [Bergström's inequality](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/BergstromInequality.shtml) or [Sedrakyan's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality)).

When $r = p+1$, it becomes [Radon's inequality](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/RadonInequality.shtml).

When $p=1$, it becomes the form posed in this question.

Comment: The first link cannot work. I found one "Wu, Sh.-H., A class of new Radon type inequalities and their applications, Math. Practice Theory, 36 (3) (2006), 217–224"

Answer (score 2):

For non-negatives $a_i$ it's just Holder for three sequences:
$$n^{m-2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i^m}{x_i}=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n1\right)^{m-2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i^m}{x_i}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(1^{m-2}\cdot \frac{a_i^m}{x_i}\cdot x_i\right)^{\frac{1}{m-2+1+1}}\right)^{m-2+1+1}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\right)^m}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}.$$
For example, for positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a^2(b+c)}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)}.$$

Comment: Right, it follows directly from Holder's inequality, but then again, so does Titu's Lemma and that gets its own special billing. Was wondering if there are any references of the inequality in the above form, which I feel makes it more obvious to apply in certain situations. Your example is a good one - it's not so obvious to me were that 3 came from, but using the inequality in that form, it's clear that the 3 is from the n^(m-2) factor where n = 3 and m = 3.

Comment: @user1301930  It's just Holder and in this form it's known and  very useful. Also, I really don't agree with naming Titu's Lemma. C-S was written in this form much more before than Titu Andreescu was born.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is a proof to my long time puzzle:$$
\sum _{i=1}^n\frac{a_i^{\alpha }}{b_i}\ge n^{2-\alpha }\frac{\left(\sum _{i=1}^na_i\right)^{\alpha }}{\sum _{i=1}^nb_i}.
$$ By the way, $m\ge1$ (here $\alpha=m$) in the answer.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, I looked more carefully at the details and have been still wondering how one could think of such an amazing application of Holder's inequality. Ps. The $1^{m−1}$ in the inner double brackets on the second line shall be $1^{m−2}$?

Comment: @MathArt It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!